# WIX bootstrapper UI Titlebar color change

Tags: installation, wix, burn

I create a WIX bundle with prerequistics. Now our requirment is to change the titlebar color to white instead of windows standard blue.

Using theme can we able to do it.

```
<Theme xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/thmutil/2010">
<Window Width="485" Height="300" HexStyle="100a0000" FontId="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" >#(loc.Caption)</Window>
<Font Id="0" Height="-12" Weight="500" Foreground="000000" Background="FFFFFF">Segoe UI</Font>
```

THis is my custom theme window code. I added Background inside WIndow tag, but thats not working. DO we have any method to change title bar color in bootstrapper UI

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for changing the title bar color. This is not something that Windows supports without being responsible for drawing all of the window chrome.

The XML schema is the `Thmutil` schema available at https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/.

Comment: I found [this Burn theme example](https://github.com/frederiksen/Classic-WiX-Burn-Theme) way back - haven't looked at it much. I seem to recall some sort of duplicated identifiers in those two Sample projects (Sample1 and Sample2 - keep an eye out for that).